# drscheme - finite state machine

Tags: scheme, racket, fsm

thanks to people at this great site I managed to put together code that is nearly complete and working. I have one final question.

here is the code:

```
     (define (chartest ch)
       (lambda (x) (char=? x ch)))

     (define fsm-trans
        '((A (lambda (x) (string=? x "a") B), (B (lambda (x) (string=? x "a") C)))))

     (define (find-next-state state ch trl)
       (cond
         [(empty? trl) false] 
         [(and (symbol=? state (first (first trl)))
              ((second (first trl)) ch))
          (third (first trl))]
         [else (find-next-state state ch (rest trl))]))


     (define fsm-final '(C))

     (define start-state 'A)

     (define (run-fsm start trl final input)
       (cond
         [(empty? input)
          (cond
            [(member start final) true]
            [else false])]
         [else 
          (local ((define next (find-next-state start (first input) trl)))
            (cond
              [(boolean? next) false]
              [else (run-fsm next trl final (rest input))]))]))


     (run-fsm start-state fsm-trans fsm-final (string->list "ac"))
```

i have a problem with the transition function find-next-state. How can I define it in order to test the incoming characters and based on this either return true value when the fsm reaches final state or false value when it doesn't?

Thank you for your answer.

UPDATE:

Thank you for your answer and I am sorry that the code is confusing.
I have repaired the definition of transtitions which now looks like this:

```
    (define fsm-trans
       '((A (lambda (x) (string=? x "a") B)
         (B (lambda (x) (string=? x "a") C)))))
```

But now I am trying to define the transition function. When I haven't had fixed transition character and I used char-alphabetic? and char-numeric?, these lines of code worked like a charm:

```
    (define (find-next-state state ch trl)
      (cond
        [(empty? trl) false] 
        [(and (symbol=? state (first (first trl)))
             ((second (first trl)) ch))
         (third (first trl))]
        [else (find-next-state state ch (rest trl))]))
```

But what should I change to work with the new definition of states in fsm-trans?
When this code is entered in DrScheme, it shows up an error with line: ((second (first trl)) ch)).

Thank you for your further assistance!

Comment: You have updated the question in a way that is *still* broken -- if you want to use quotes, copy the first example I used *exactly as it is* -- those are *backquotes* and *commas* there.  But like I said, it is **much better** for you to use the second example at this stage.

Comment: @Eli Barzilay: When I use the second example it gives me an error concerning the B. It said that it expected only one expression within lambda, but found one extra part in: B. Now I am not sure which definition I should use. Thank you for your answer. The only way I made it work was like this: (define fsm-trans
  (list (list 'A (lambda (x) ((string=? x "a") 'B)))
        (list 'B (lambda (x) ((string=? x "a") 'C)))))

Comment: You are probably working with the student languages.  If this is required for your course, then you'll need to ask your instructor for advice on how you should write your code.  If not, then you should switch to the plain racket language (using `#lang racket`, and set the language to the "detect language in source" setting.)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the main problem in this code is a confusion over quotes, quasiquotes and unquotes.  Specifically, `'(foo (lambda (x) x) baz)` is quoting the *whole* thing, so there is no function there, just a symbolic representation for one.  Also, your use of `,` looks like you're confusing it as something that separates values in a list.  Another problem is that the parens look mismatched.  You probably want something like this instead, using a quasiquote:

```
(define fsm-trans
  `((A ,(lambda (x) (string=? x "a") B))
    (B ,(lambda (x) (string=? x "a") C))))
```

**But** given that you're unclear about these things, then it'll be **much** better to stick to simple quotes only, and use `list` when needed:

```
(define fsm-trans
  (list (list 'A (lambda (x) (string=? x "a") B))
        (list 'B (lambda (x) (string=? x "a") C))))
```

You probably have some more problems to get over, but doing that should get you in the right direction.

Comment: This answer is still what you're looking for.